# Passing -Dlogging.config=logback.xml to Spring Boot 3.1.2 and GraalVM native image

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, graalvm-native-image, spring-logback

In our previous non-native setup we passed over Helms following parameter to specify concrete logback.xml.

```
java -jar executable.jar -Dlogging.config=/workspace/logback.xml
```

After switching to the native image it doesn't work out of the box. When I run on a pod:

```
/cnb/process/web -Dlogging.config=/workspace/logback.xml
```

I got following error:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from '/workspace/logback.xml'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.model.processor.ImplicitModelHandler - Could not create component [encoder] of type [net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender[json] - No encoder set for the appender named "json".
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reportConfigurationErrorsIfNecessary(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:260)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:247)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:187)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:298)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:246)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:223)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.multicastInitialEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:136)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:64)
    at java.base@17.0.7/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:356)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
```

Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Any news about this error ? I got the same